# Godot setting anchor to "full rect" doesn't stretch the background image across entire game play field

Tags: godot, godot4

I am following a book example of Chris Bradfield "Godot 4 Gave Development Projects - Build Five cross platform 2D and 3D games 2nd Edition".

I am at the stage of having a very simple game "Coin Dash" where an animated fox can collect randomly spawn animated coins. Next stage is to take a green grass tile background image and stretch it over entire gameplay field, the author of the book claims:

> Add the following nodes as children of Main:
> • A TextureRect node
> named Background – for the background image
> • A Timer node named
> GameTimer – for the countdown timer
> >
> Make sure Background is the first
> child node by dragging it above the player in the node list. Nodes are
> drawn in the order shown in the tree, so if Background is first, that
> ensures it’s drawn behind the player. Add an image to the Background
> node by dragging the grass.png image from the assets folder into the
> Texture property. Change Stretch Mode to Tile, and then set the size
> to Full Rect by clicking the layout button at the top of the editor
> window:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mtOL.png

[My project structure looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luSD0.png)

[And yet the 2D screen after setting the stretch mode to tile looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ps4p.png)

While the game works no problem, that little square in the top left screen corner should cover entire game play field and it doesn't. The frustration of a noob following a deceiving book is real since I have so little knowledge to juggle what is wrong in here:

[Actual running game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpU7E.png)

The main script is as follows:

```
extends Node
@export var coin_scene : PackedScene
@export var playtime = 30
var level = 1
var score = 0
var time_left = 0
var screensize = Vector2.ZERO
var playing = false

func _ready():
    screensize = get_viewport().get_visible_rect().size
    $Player.screensize = screensize
    $Player.hide()
    new_game()
    
func new_game():
    playing = true
    level = 1
    score = 0
    time_left = playtime
    $Player.start()
    $Player.show()
    $GameTimer.start()
    spawn_coins()
    
func spawn_coins():
    for i in level + 4:
        var c = coin_scene.instantiate()
        c.screensize = screensize
        add_child(c)
        c.position = Vector2(randi_range(0, screensize.x), randi_range(0, screensize.y))
```

[Setting up full rect as anchor size and set "Stretch Mode" to "Tile"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88I7i.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Main` (the roof of the scene) is a `Node2D` (I know it is a `Node2D` because it has a blue circle icon).

And as `Node2D` it does not have an size (yes, some `Node2D` have a concept of size by virtue of having a texture, but that is not true for `Node2D` in general, nor would it help here).

So when `Background` tries to expand to the "Full Rect" of its parent, it can't. Because, to reiterate, its parent `Main` does not have a size.

I have three options for you…

---

**Option A**

- Change the type of `Main` to be a `Node`

I believe this is the intention of the author, given that your script is defined to extend `Node`.

The way this works is that the `Control` will disregard the parent `Node`, so it takes the size of the parent `Viewport` (which is the root of the scene tree, the same one you get with `get_viewport`).

---

**Option B**

- Change the type of `Main` to be a `Control`
- Set it to "Full Rect"

The way this works is that the `Main` node will take the size of the parent viewport, so the background can take the size from it.

---

**Option C**

- Set the size of `Background` from the `Main` script.

You are already getting the size for the purpose of limiting the area where the coins can spawn. You can also set that size to `Background`.

*By the way, you might want to handle the [`size_changed`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_viewport.html#class-viewport-signal-size-changedt) signal of the `Viewport`, you can connect to it via code, see [Using Signals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html).*

Comment: absolutely brilliant answer - option A works and yes the author wanted me to create "Node" not "Node2D" , no way I'd spot this myself. Thanks for other options too, makes it bookmarkable.